# Not displaying all data in C using struct

Tags: c, struct, io, printf

So I have this simple program in C that I am working on to help me understand structures. There is nothing too complicated about it. However when it gets to the point where it should display the data, it only displays part of the data. The program asks a user for a first and last name, then an amount. Then it should display the first and last name, as well as the amount. It does not display the last name. I am sure this is probably something simple, but I am not sure what I am missing here.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define NAMESIZE 30 

    struct data{
         float amount;
         char firstName[NAMESIZE];
         char lastName [NAMESIZE];
    }record;

    int main()
    {
         printf("\nEnter the donor's first and last names \n");
         printf("Separate names by a space: ");
         scanf("%s, %s", record.firstName, record.lastName);
 
         char c;
         while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF )
              {
         }
 
         // At this point the program does not work correctly
         // It will just print the first name not the last name
         printf("\nEnter the donation amount: ");
         scanf("%f", &record.amount);

         // Display the information
         printf("\nDonor %s %s gave $%.2f \n", record.firstName, record.lastName, record.amount);

    return 0;
     }
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Once I got rid of the extra comma in the first scanf call, it worked. Here is the line that got corrected:

```
             scanf("%s %s", record.firstName, record.lastName);
```

I had a comma between the two %s, and that was incorrect.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf.` In the code the `printf` says ""Separate names by a space: " but there is a comma in the `scanf`. What is the actual input?

Comment: 1) Look in your debugger to SEE if you got a last name.  You ARE using a debugger, right?  2) Check the return value (e.g. `iret = scanf()` to verify the #/items read is "2".  Checking return values is Good :) 3) Get rid of the comma: change to `iret = scanf("%s %s", record.firstName, record.lastName);`

Comment: `scanf("%s, %s", <...>);` --> `scanf("%s %s", <...>);`

Comment: I thought the comma had to be there for scanf to work properly?

Comment: Thank you paulsm4 and user12986714, once I made that change, it worked as is should, thank you for pointing out my simple mistake.

Comment: No, any comma in the *format string* is a literal `','` that must be in the input. You use commas to separate the pointer arguments after the format string.... You must VALIDATE every user-input, e.g. `if (scanf("%s %s", record.firstName, record.lastName) != 2) { fputs ("error: EOF encountered before both names read.\n", stderr); exit (EXIT_FAILRE); }` and include `stdlib.h` for the definition of `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` (`0/1`) macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe can use fgets that have buffer overflow protected and use strtok to split the spacing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    #define NAMESIZE 30 

    struct data{
         float amount;
         char firstName[NAMESIZE];
         char lastName [NAMESIZE];
    }record;

    int main()
    {
        char *name = malloc(NAMESIZE);
        if (name == NULL) {
        printf("No memory\n");
        return 1;
        }

         printf("\nEnter the donor's first and last names \n");
         printf("Separate names by a space: ");
         //scanf("%s, %s", record.firstName, record.lastName);
         fgets(name, NAMESIZE, stdin);

        if ((strlen(name) > 0) && (name[strlen (name) - 1] == '\n'))
            name[strlen (name) - 1] = '\0';

        //split name
    int init_size = strlen(name);
    char delim[] = " ";

    char *ptr = strtok(name, delim);
    int idx = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d '%s'\n",idx, ptr);
                if(idx == 0){
          strcpy(record.firstName, ptr);
                }
                else{
                  strcpy(record.lastName, ptr);
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        idx += 1;
    }

     /*
         char c;
         while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF )
              {
         }
         */
         // At this point the program does not work correctly
         // It will just print the first name not the last name
         printf("\nEnter the donation amount: ");
         scanf("%f", &record.amount);

         // Display the information
         printf("\nDonor %s %s gave $%.2f \n", record.firstName, record.lastName, record.amount);

    free(name);
    return 0;
     }
```